# How to customize scripts for closed accordion default in completed menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created an accordion menu for Mobiles using the following and it works well.  I want to apply a jquery to make it default to closed all sections.

In header:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Jaldi:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
<!-- CSS reset -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<!-- Resource style -->
<script src="js/modernizr.js"></script>
```

My ready code is:

```
<ul class="cd-accordion-menu animated">
<li class="has-children">
<input type="checkbox" name ="group-1" id="group-1" checked>
<label for="group-1"><strong>
<font-color: "white">
&nbsp;&nbsp;MENU: CLICK OPEN, CLICK CLOSE</strong></font></label>
<ul>
<li><a href="../index.shtml" target="_self">Home</a></li>
<li class="has-children">
<input type="checkbox" name ="sub-group-1" id="sub-group-1">
<label for="sub-group-1">+ About us</label>
<ul>
<li><a href="../virtualcenter.html" target="_self">Virtual Center Studies</a></li>
<li><a href="../contact.html" target="_self">Contact Us</a></li>
<li class="has-children">
<input type="checkbox" name ="sub-group-2" id="sub-group-2">
<label for="sub-group-2">+ Correspondence and Links</label>
<ul>
<li><a href="../testimonial.html" target="_self">Am I </a></li>
<li><a href="../letters.html" target="_self">Letters to Editor</a></li>
<li><a href="../Online-Resources.html" target="_self">Related Links</a></li>
<li><a href="../open-letters.html" target="_self">Open Letters</a></li>
</ul>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="has-children">
<input type="checkbox" name ="sub-group-3" id="sub-group-3">
<label for="sub-group-3">+ History</label>
<ul>
<li><a href="../modknow.html" target="_self">Archaeology</a></li>
[snip] -- more of the same
Ending with:
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script> 
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

Jquery which I want to use is:

```
<script>
jQuery(function($){
    $('.et_pb_accordion .et_pb_toggle_open').addClass('et_pb_toggle_close').removeClass('et_pb_toggle_open');

    $('.et_pb_accordion .et_pb_toggle').click(function() {
      $this = $(this);
      setTimeout(function(){
         $this.closest('.et_pb_accordion').removeClass('et_pb_accordion_toggling');
      },700);
    });
});
</script>
```

I do NOT know how to customize the JQuery above to make it work on my code.

Thanks.

Comment: As I see your menu has class `cd-accordion-menu`, so try something like this - `$('.cd-accordion-menu').addClass('et_pb_toggle_close').removeClass('et_pb_toggle_open');`

Comment: Thanks.  When I add
$('.cd-accordion-menu').addClass('et_pb_toggle_close').remov‌​eClass('et_pb_toggle‌​_open');
I get script Error

Answer (score 0):

No more answers required.  I found the answer and it is very simple: Change of: 'input type="checkbox" name ="group-1" id="group-1" checked'  to:
'input type="checkbox" data-toggle="collapse" name ="group-1" id="group-1"'